# Solovay Theorem

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Solovay's Theorem states

> If $\kappa$ is regular uncountable, then any stationary set in $\kappa$ can be partitioned into $\kappa$-many pairwise disjoint stationary sets.

For regular uncountable *successor* $\kappa$, this follows from a result by Ulam [Kunen, p.79].

My questions are:

1) Can I apply the theorem for $\kappa=\mathfrak c =2^\omega$, when CH fails ($\mathfrak c >\omega_1$)? (is $\mathfrak c$ necessarily regular?).

2) Might I be able to prove the special case in (1) using methods less sophisticated than those found in Solovay's proof? Something like Ulam's matrix?

Thanks!

Comment: The only requirement in $\sf ZFC$ that $\frak c$ must satisfy is that $\operatorname{cf}(\mathfrak c)>\aleph_0$. In particular it is consistent that $\mathfrak c=\aleph_{\omega_1}$, in which case it is singular, and the theorems no longer apply.

Comment: Pretty much the proof will come down to whether $\mathfrak{c}$ is a successor cardinal or simply just regular.  If it is successor than you can use an Ulam matrix, whereas if it is just regular I believe you will have to use Solovay's approach.  And as Asaf points out it is consisten that $\mathfrak{c}$ is singular in which case neither method work.

Comment: Solovay's approach is really not that complicated, in hindsight. (The presentation in **Introduction to Cardinal Arithmetic**, by M. Holz, K. Steffens, and E. Weitz is particularly accessible.) I do not know of a proof specific to the continuum, or of any "easy" approaches for (small?) weakly inaccessibles.

Comment: Ok thanks everyone. For the theorem I am trying to prove, maybe I don't need something this strong anyway. Andres - I read that the proof involves forcing. You are saying now there is an elementary proof?

Comment: What are you trying to prove? It might be the case that the continuum is provably regular under your assumptions; or that something else can be distilled from the starting conditions...

Comment: Asaf - Too much to state here, let me reevaluate things and I will edit this or ask a new question.  Thanks

Comment: There is no forcing anywhere in the proof.

Comment: See theorem 3 [here](http://andrescaicedo.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/580-partition-calculus-3/).